# Открытие окна с параметрами

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Сделал на страничке форму, она отдаёт через POST переменные на нужную php-страницу.

```
<form method=post action='".$root."/(...тут путь...)/page.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='first' value='$second'>
<input type='hidden' name='second' value='$first'>
<input type='submit' value='кноПКа' onclick='WindowOpen2()' style='cursor:pointer;'>
</form>
```

Всё нормально (если без скрипта), **НО** есть необходимость открывать страницу в новом окне с заданными параметрами. Использую JS через функцию `window.open`:

```
<script language='javascript'>
function WindowOpen2()
{
window.open('".$root."/(...тут путь...)/page.php','0x0','toolbar=no, status=no, scrollbars=no, location=no, menubar=no, directories=no, width=360, height=504, top=200, left=400')
}
</script>
```

Вот как в это окно получить данные от вышеуказанных input'ов?
Заранее благодарен за внимание к вопросу - I.CaR®

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собираем значение инпутов и посылаем через get. Проще всего реализовать, используя jQuery. Перепишем немножко.

```
//задаем id форме
<form id="form1" method=post action='".$root."/(...тут путь...)/page.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='first' value='$second'>
    <input type='hidden' name='second' value='$first'>
    <input type='submit' value='кноПКа' onclick='WindowOpen2()' style='cursor:pointer;'>
</form>

<script language='javascript'>
function WindowOpen2()
{
    //собираем значения инпутов, и посылаем GET ом
    window.open('".$root."/(...тут путь...)/page.php?' + $('#form1').serialize(), '0x0','toolbar=no, status=no, scrollbars=no, location=no, menubar=no, directories=no, width=360, height=504, top=200, left=400')
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ага, тоже не дождавшись ответа реализовал практически тем же методом.
У меня не одна форма.

    <script language='JavaScript'> 
    function createLink(form) 
    { 
    var link = form.action+'?'
    for (var l = 0; l<form.elements.length; l++) 
        { 
        link+=form.elements[l].name+'='+form.elements[l].value 
        if (l!=form.elements.length-1) link+='&' 
        } 
    window.open(link,'window','width=360,height=504') 
    } 
    </script>

и form'a

    <form action='".$root."/(...тут путь...)/page.php' onSubmit='createLink(this);return false'>

Большое СПАСИБО Вам! за отклик

Answer (score 1):

```
<form target="_blank">...</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method=post action='".$root."/(...тут путь...)/page.php' target='имя окна которое откроет функция WindowOpen2' onsubmit='WindowOpen2();return true;'>
```

а из кнопки submit можно просто изъять ваш Onclick